# A question about type D visa, professional driver in Germany from a non-EU country

Tags: visa, germany, immigration

I wanted to work in Germany and since the I'm from an non-EU country I thought I might use my driving license to go as a professional truck-driver. Since I automatically get a type D Visa, I wanted to ask if it is possible to change job entirely when there? let's say from a truck-driver to a waiter or the sort.

On the visa a couple of people I know have this stamped:

> BESCHÄFTIGUNG Gemäß  19C ABS. 1 AUFENTHG I.V.M.  24A ABS. 2 BESCHV **NUR ERLAUBT ALS
> BAUHELFER/LKW-FAHRER BEI *XXXXXXX*** and ofc SELBSTSTÄNDIGE TÄTIGKEIT NICHT ERLAUBT

Does anybody have any info on this?

Comment: Since your visa explicitly states that you may work as a **CONSTRUCTION WORKER/TRUCK DRIVER** (Google Translate result of **BAUHELFER/LKW-FAHRER**) and only at the firm XXXXXXX, the answer to your question should be clear since 'a waiter or the sort' is neither one or the other and that any employment only by XXXXXXX is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing job entirely would not be possible with such a restriction.

From [Ordinance on the Employment of Foreigners, Section 34, Limitation of Approval](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_beschv/englisch_beschv.html#p0247)

> (1) The Federal Employment Agency may limit approval to engage in employment with regard to
>
> 1. the period of validity,
> 2. the establishment,
> 3. the professional activity,
> 4. the employer,
> 5. the region in which the employment can be engaged in, and
> 6. the location and distribution of working hours.

As @Mark Johnson comments:
“Since your visa explicitly states that you may work as a CONSTRUCTION WORKER/TRUCK DRIVER (Google Translate result of BAUHELFER/LKW-FAHRER) and only at the firm XXXXXXX, the answer to your question should be clear since 'a waiter or the sort' is neither one or the other and that any employment only by XXXXXXX is allowed.”